# PHP MVC not sending value to controller

Tags: php, mysql

I have been making a MVC site, I am having trouble sending the row id from my form to my controller.

The code that I am using for my form gets the row ID for each db entry and assigns it to a hidden value. When the form is submitted it sends the parameters to the controller (should send $uid) but the uid isn't making it to the controller.

**Form Code (buttons.php)**

```
<?php
    $itemsDAO = new ItemsDAO();
    $result = $itemsDAO->getItems();
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        $uid = $row['id'];
?>
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
    <fieldset>
    <input id='action' type='hidden' name='action' value='deleteItem' />
    <p>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="hidden" id="fId" name="fId" value="<?php echo  $uid; ?>">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Delete">
        </div>
    </div>
    </p>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
<?php } ?>
```

**Controller function**

```
function deleteItem($parameters) {
    $id=$parameters["fId"];

    if ($this->model->deleteItem( $id )) {
        $this->model->hasDeleteFailed = false;
        $this->model->setDeleteItemConfirmation();
        return (true);
    }
    else
        $this->model->deleteItemError ( DELETE_ITEM_ERROR_STR );
}
```

**View.php** - where I am showing the list of db items and the buttons.php

```
$this->model->prepareItemList();
$buttons = file_get_contents( "templates/buttons.php");
$HTMLItemList = "";
foreach ( $this->model->itemList as $row ) 
        $HTMLItemList .= "<li><strong>" . $row ["title"] . ": </strong>" . $row ["price"] . "<blockquote>" .$row ["description"] .  " " . $buttons ."</blockquote></li>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay,

1. step by step the  $uid has to first make it into the form elements value attribute. Check the html source code to make sure this is actually happening.
2. place var_dump($_POST) exit; in your controller to find what is actually being recieved if anything at all.
3. check to make sure your result array element actual has a value and not an empty string value or NULL.

Hmm S.O. code formatting bad.

```
   // turn on error reporting for dev to view empty or missing  variable errors
   ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
   $result=$itemsDAO->getItems();
   foreach ($result as $row) {
       ($row['id'] != ''? $uid = $row['id'] : $uid ='no id found');
       // debug result
       echo '<pre>' . print_r($row,1) .'</pre>';
   }
```

Comment: I have figured out that it is the form code that is giving me the issue, I tested the code by hard coding in some value and that work perfectly, but I cant see why the $uid value isnt being assigned to the value

Comment: Yes I was going to mention this earlier but opted to have you check the form  value first.  In many frameworks a

Comment: See if the $uid is being treated as a string.

Comment: @CarlMcDade would you be able to show me in the code? I still cant figure it out

Comment: added a change to my answer in code to validate the result value

Comment: I still cant get this to work, i just dont understand why the $uid isnt being assigned to the value

Comment: added a debug line.  Could be that the database is empty or there is no result from the database.

Comment: The database is all fine because if I hard code a row id value into the form and then go to the front end and click delete the row that I have hard coded gets deleted

Comment: And you are positive  $result=$itemsDAO->getItems();  is returning something? How are you testing this?

Comment: No this isnt returning anything and is causing all the problems

Comment: So all of the code in your  original post is useless. You  need to go back and deeper to before $result=$itemsDAO->getItems(); is called. What framework are you using?  Looks like laravel or codeignighter.

Comment: I amnt too sure what frame work it is I have just been following some tutorials, I added in the line `$itemsDAO = new ItemsDAO();` thinking i hadnt initialise the itemsDAO but that didnt help either

Comment: Without  seeing the entire code from back to front and having debug at each stage I am going to diagnose that this is a either being a punctuation mistake or a typo in a name somewhere while trying to connect and get info from the db. Is this your  pastebin ? http://pastebin.com/UsRjftbC

Answer (score 1):

Try `$_POST["fld"];` in your controller to get value. If you are using any framework like codeigniter then you can use its own methods.

For example codeigniter has

```
$this->input->post();
```